# How do I get dwarves to be sane about their armor?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Initially, my dwarves were training (and charging headlong into combat) without armor, just normal clothing. Thanks to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122560/making-dwarves-wear-armor-and-wield-a-weapon), I discovered two settings:

- In the military screen (<kbd>m</kbd>), I can set their armor to "Replace (<kbd>r</kbd>)" their clothing. This resulted in the military immediately stripping naked, and putting on *some* armor. For example, Urist McBreezypants is currently wearing just a pair of high boots.
- The squad orders pane (<kbd>s</kbd>) has a <kbd>t</kbd> active/inactive. They seem to be doing a "Combat drill", which is more than they've ever done. Hopefully this raises their skill levels a bit, as they're all currently “Dabbling Eyepoker” or “Novice Kneebreaker”, essentially.

That said, how can I get Urist McStreaker to put some clothing on? The trading depot has plenty of available pieces of armor (mail shirts, for example! made of metal, even.) My dwarves' uniform is all metal armor, but not more specific than that. I.e.,

- metal armor
- metal headwear
- metal legwear
- metal handwear
- metal footwear
- etc.

Comment: I removed the bit asking about bone because it should likely be asked as a separate question.

Comment: Ditto for the waterfall bit.

Comment: Speaking of which, I wouldn't set them to replace their clothes - they can normally just put the armour over the top. That way if you don't have enough full sets of armour to go around your militia, they'll at lest be decent. Or as decent as dwarves ever are...

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your dwarves don't want to take it from the trading depot. Instead you should designate stockpiles for armor and weapons and your military dwarves should collect gear from there. The gear should be transferred to the stockpiles by haulers, assuming that you have not actually designated gear in the depot for trading.

Comment: That sounds unlikely.

Comment: This is almost certain. Only armor in stockpiles is eligible to be claimed by military dwarves. If all your junk is in the trade depot, the soldiers can't get it.

Comment: Tried this. Designated two separate stockpiles using the armor & weapons defaults. The dwarves promptly hauled the items (they didn't bin/barrel the armor: is that possible?), but the military still ignores the nice shiny mail shirt.

Comment: They can bin armor, or they can put it on armor stands in a barracks designated for equipment. If that wasn't the problem I'm not sure anything else stands out at obviously wrong. Maybe you set them to wear no armor during civilian duties? (Don't ever do that)